# Strip or generalize all the functions calls parameter in SQL String using regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I have many sqls calls which will be printed in logger which have table valued function calls we want to generalize it so that we can get better counts and stats in splunk.

We have below kind of sqls in map will be printed in logs

```
select * from dbo.function1(param1, (param2), '121,3232,424', (param4) ) join dbo.functions2(param1, param2);
```

```
select * from dbo.function1(param1) join function2('demo','12134,4343,4343')
```

There could  be sqls with join or without join with "," or without "," and there could be queries with inner query as well like below :-

```
select col1, col2 from table1, (select col1, col2 from funct1(param1, param2) a join table2 b on a.id=b.id ) table2;
```

we want to generalize it to like below :-

```
select * from dbo.function1(stripped) join dbo.functions2(stripped);
```

```
select * from dbo.function1(stripped) join function2(stripped)
```

```
select col1, col2 from table1, (select col1, col2 from funct1(stripped) a join table2 b on a.id=b.id ) table2;
```

so that we can get the counts for the sql with diff parameter as well.
The challenge is of two brackets , either it is going for greedy, or it is going just till first closing bracket.
As of now the regex we have made is like below

```
"[ ][_0-9a-z]{0,30}[.]?[_0-9a-z]{5,128}([(].*?[)])"
```

this regex will print the match till `dbo.function1(param1, (param2)` so how to go till last bracket for this function call.
Also need to handle inbuilt functions, had handled by giving the length of 5 to avoid the function max(), min but still there are function like COALESCE() and others.

Comment: [^(]+\\((.*)\\)\bjoin\b[^(]+\\((.*)\\);?$

Answer (score 0):

**This might help:**

```
input.replaceAll("(select \\* from [^\\(]+).*?( join [^\\(]+)[^;]+, "$1(stripped)$2(stripped)");
```

Testbench:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "select * from dbo.function1(param1, (param2), '121,3232,424', "
            + "(param4) ) join dbo.functions2(param1, param2);\n\n"
            + "select * from dbo.function1(param1) join function2('demo','12134,4343,4343')\n";

    String result =
            input.replaceAll("(select \\* from [^\\(]+).*?( join [^\\(]+)[^;]+"
                    , "$1(stripped)$2(stripped)");

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Output:

```
select * from dbo.function1(stripped) join dbo.functions2(stripped);

select * from dbo.function1(stripped) join function2(stripped)
```